# silverlight support in vs2010

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0, windows-ce, silverlight-embedded

hi i need some clarification about silverlight.
I want develop one silverlightapplication for win ce6.0.
so that my question is visualstudio2010 .net framework will no support for wince.
is silverlight will support in visual studio2005 and tel me the detailed description or links about that.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to develop some Silverlight for Windows Embedded using with VS2010 or VS2005.  Bear in mind you will be really developing in a form of Silverlight 2 not 4.

See [Silveright for Windows Embedded](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee502198.aspx) for details.

Answer (score 0):

Afaik, Silverlight is only supported on the newer Windows Phone 7 devices.

Comment: Silverlight has been around a lot longer than the WP7